# Unable to replace forward slash with back slash and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, regex

**Javascript:**

```
var str = 'som\\//kdshn/jasdj/\akdjsl/kas\asd';
var newstr = str.replace(/(\\|\/)/g,function(a, m) { return m == "/" ? "\\" : "//"; });
```

> Result: `som//\\kdshn\jasdj\akdjsl\kasasd`.

In the result backslash is getting escaped. How to handle?

Comment: If  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393199/3832970 worked for you please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You doubled the slash by using `"//"`.

If you swap a single backslash with a forward slash, `"/"` will do.

Use

```
var newstr = str.replace(/[\\\/]/g,function(a) { return a == "/" ? "\\" : "/"; });
```

It yields `som/\\kdshn\jasdj\akdjsl\kasasd`.

```js
var str = 'som\\//kdshn/jasdj/\akdjsl/kas\asd';
var newstr = str.replace(/[\\\/]/g,function(a) { return a == "/" ? "\\" : "/"; });
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens is that your backslash becomes a forward slash, which then gets computed as an ASCII character.

For example:

```
var test = "foo\bar\foobar"
```

becomes

```
"fooaroobar"
```

And that's because \b and \f do not exist.

You should instead do:

```
var test = "foo\\bar\\foobar"
```

Be careful when using forward backslashes ;)